# Wordpress theme custom single view page [Sage roots]

Tags: wordpress, roots-sage

So my wordpress theme is based on **Sage theme** by **roots**, I wanted to create a custom page (different header, footer etc..) from the current theme.

(So the basic idea behind this is to create a simple page which will act as a knowledge base page for our mobile app)

I achieved this by creating a custom template `template-custom.php` but how can I create a custom single page which inherits from the new template instead of Sage's `base.php` (As you may know this is Sage default wrapper)

Comment: I believe it looks for a template by template-'pagename', see [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) or [template hierachy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Comment: From latest Sage 9.0.1, there is a `page.blade.php` in the `resources/views/` folder. What is your Sage version ?